How to remove the font from list in jodit-react
I am trying to remove some font formatting options from the Jodit pre-defined list. I tried some way around unfortunately its giving an issue posted below.
Issue:
The test cases are breaking giving the below error:
screenshot of the issue
I am using React + typescript with Jest
The implementation works correct however the test cases are breaking.
It would be very greatfull if anyone could provide your valuable inputs.
Thanks in advance.
    import { Jodit } from "jodit";
    import JoditEditor, { IJoditEditorProps, Jodit as TJodit } from "jodit-react";

    const joditConfig = useMemo(
    () => ({
        toolbar: true,
        controls: {
        paragraph: {
            list: Jodit.atom({
            p: "Pharagraph",
            h1: "Heading 1",
            h2: "Heading 2",
            h3: "Heading 3",
            }),
        },
        },
    }),
    []
    );
    <JoditEditor config={joditConfig} />


